# How to add autoincremental field in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo, auto-increment, openerp-7

I searched and modified the source code of a simple custom module of openerp, I give the code below

**init**.py

```
import sim
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
'name': 'Student Information Management',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is for the Student Information Management.""",
'author': 'Mr Praveen Srinivasan',
    'website': 'http://praveenlearner.wordpress.com/',
'depends': ['base'],
'data': ['sim_view.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

sim_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ============== student================= -->
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_form">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Student" version="7.0">
<group>
<field name="reg_no"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
<field name="address"/>
</group>
</form>
</field>
</record>
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view end-->

<!--2nd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_tree">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<tree string="Student">
<field name="reg_no"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
<field name="address"/>
</tree>
</field>
</record>
<!--2nd part of the sim_view end-->

<!-- 3rd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_student">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="res_model">sim.student</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!--3rd part of the sim_view end-->

<!--4th part of the sim_view start-->
<menuitem name="SIM/Student/StudentInfo" id="menu_sim_student"  
      action="action_student"/>
<!--4th part of the sim_view end-->
</data>
</openerp>
```

sim.py

```
**

    from openerp.osv import fields, osv
    class student(osv.osv):
        _name = "sim.student"
        _description = "This table is for keeping personal data of student"
        _columns = {
            'reg_no': fields.integer('Registration Number',size=7,required=True),
            'student_name': fields.char('Student Name',size=25,required=True),
            'father_name': fields.char("Father's Name",size=25),
            'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
            'contact_no':fields.char('Contact Number',size=10),
            'address':fields.char('Address',size=256)
        }
        _sql_constraints = [
        ('uniq_name', 'unique(reg_no)', 'This Reg.No is number already registered!') 
        ]

    student()

**
```

All is working good, but I want to add an auto incremented registration Id field. I searched the Internet how to do it, but I can't get a proper solution. Please help me.

Comment: i don't understand properly. you want your field "reg_no" to be incremented on creation of records? like sale order names are incremented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating sequence file you can add this function to your sim.py

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    sequence=self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'reg_code')
    vals['reg_no']=sequence
    return super(student, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

This function will work properly

Comment: I can confirm it works the best. The other answer always skips a number, i.e. it looks like `0001`, `0003`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Create a record in ir.sequence. First make your reg_no field to char.

```
<record id="seq_type_1" model="ir.sequence.type"> 
  <field name="name">REG Type</field> 
  <field name="code">reg_code</field> 
</record> 
<record id="seq_1" model="ir.sequence"> 
    <field name="name">reg</field> 
    <field name="code">reg_code</field> 
    <field name="prefix">REG</field> 
    <field name="padding">3</field> 
</record>
```

In your py file you can define when to generate the sequence. Either in defaults to get default reg number or override the create method and call the sequence Or in any other methods:

_defaults = { 'reg_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'reg_code'), }